# regular expression validator to check if string has number

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to implement asp.net regularexpression validator and want to check if string contains number or not. Its ok to have string containing number only

I tried below but its not working

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rfvMyCode" runat="server"  ValidationGroup="ValidationSave" ControlToValidate="txtMyCode"
                ErrorMessage="String must have a Number" ForeColor="#FF3300" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to validate that the string must contain at least one number, you can use `.*\d.*` regex  [regex](https://regex101.com/r/gz9YyP/1)

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rfvMyCode" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationSave"
    ControlToValidate="txtMyCode" ErrorMessage="String must have a Number" ForeColor="#FF3300"
    ValidationExpression=".*\d.*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

`.*`  means "0 or more of any character"

`\d` matches any single digit [0-9]

Answer (score -2):

```
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
        ID="rfvMyCode" 
        runat="server"  
        ValidationGroup="ValidationSave" 
        ControlToValidate="txtMyCode"
        ErrorMessage="String must have at least one Number" 
        ForeColor="#FF3300" 
        ValidationExpression="^(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$">
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

With this setup, the `RegularExpressionValidator` will ensure that the input contains at least one number while allowing a mix of letters and numbers. If the input doesn't meet this requirement, the error message "String must have at least one Number" will be displayed in red text.

Comment: This makes potentially unfounded assumptions about what a valid string looks like.